# Can't get response from the server hosted in azure

Tags: web-services, postman, azure-vm-role

I have a server which is running on the Azure's Virtual Machine. I'm trying to test it via Postman. But when I send a simple Http Get request I get "Could not get any response".

I am using following url: http://104.43.255.227/admin

I can't understand the problem. When server runs on the localhost, there is no problem to get a response with the valid data.

Has anyone of you had this problem before?
I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Virtual Machines have to be specifically configured to allow incoming traffic on a particular endpoint. By default, new Virtual Machines are only configured for endpoints for RDP (3389) and Powershell (5986).

You should add another endpoint for HTTP traffic on port 80, or HTTPS on port 443.

I could expand with more info on specifically what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is following. I can't start server's bat file. When I change ip variable for a public ip, I get java.net.BindException Cannot assign requested address.
I have created http and https endpoints.

Comment: so this is a java web application? Are jvm and jre installed on the VM?  did you create the VM yourself or are you using one of the templates?